# This is not the correct coordinator/ co-ordinator unaware of this member

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

We are getting this issue intermittently.

```
ERROR [org.springframework.kafka.KafkaListenerEndpointContainer#1-0-C-1]
  ConsumerCoordinator: [Consumer clientId=consumer-6, groupId=mysearchapp] 
  Offset commit failed on partition user_entity-0 at offset 6535: 
  This is not the correct coordinator.
```

Any suggession would be great help for me.
We are using kafka 2.2.7 version.

Comment: By version 4 do you mean **Confluent** version? With current release of **Kafka** being 2.3, I don't think version 4 exists yet.

Comment: My mistake. Question edited to set kafka version to 2.2.7.

Comment: FYI 2.2.7 is not a valid Apache Kafka version. I'm guessing it's the spring-kafka version.